# How to return a functions output

Tags: javascript, function, return

The function output(string*[1])* is underlined . I dont understand why it does not return E.

```
    function output(string[1]) {
    
    }
    
    return output;
    
 }
 countBs("hello")
```

Comment: the code is function countBs(string){
    countBs[count];
   


    
 }
 countBs("hello")


function countBs(string){
  function string[count]{
      if 
  }
}

Comment: `function output(string[1]) {` is not valid syntax, `function output(string) {` is.

Answer (score 0):

you question is incomplete which makes it hard to answer. Please post complete questions which contain a complete code which can be run by the people who try to answer your question.

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.
You define a new function. In the function definition you declare its **formal parameters** (which don't have a value assigned here) by telling their names. In this example `function output(str, index)` the formal parameters are 'str' and 'index'.

When using the function you call it with **actual parameters** which means you assign values to the formal parameter: `output("hello", 1)`

Here the complete source code:

```
function output(str, index) {
        return str[index];
}

ret = output("hello", 1);
console.log("value: " + ret);
```